# how to find standard deviation of noise in an image using matlab?

Tags: matlab

As a part of my project,  initially find low resolution of the input image. Then as a second step i need find the noise in the low-resolution image. How to find noise in an image and its standard deviation using matlab?

Comment: This question is too broad. You need to be much more specific and post a **minimum** viable example as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Please update your question.

Comment: First, share what you have tried so far.

Comment: @kkuilla what am asking is how to find or obtain the noise of an image ? then finding the standard deviation is easy...or its is difficult....is there any solution.....

Comment: @user3148302 You still haven't shared what you have tried so far (i.e. a minimum viable example). You will not get any answers that you find useful unless you do that. Please read the link I posted and update your question.

Comment: i am already done following steps   1) take input image and its low resolution by down sampling    2)divide the resultant image into 4*4 patches with 3 pixels overlapped   3)the i need to classify the patches into smooth and detail group... for this purpose i need to find the standard deviation of the noise in the LL image...for that initially i need to find the noise in LL image then calculate its standard deviation....calculation of standard deviation is easy..but my problem is how to find the noise in the LL image? then only calculation of the standard deviation is possible.plz help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `std` matlab function which returns the standard deviation of a matrix.

```
std_deviation = std(image);
```

This will give you the standard deviation of the whole image. However you cannot calculate the  noise std since you don't have the original filtered image.

Possible solution: (Not accurate) : This suppose thaht your noise is gaussian

Well, you can render several Noise matrices and test them:
(choose your `mean_vector` and `std_vector`)

`for i = 1 : length(mean_vector)  % or length(std_vector)
    Noise(:,:,i) = mean_vector(i) + std_vector(i).*randn(size(your_image))
    % extracting the possibly filtered image
    filtered_img(:,:,i) = your_image - Noise(:,:,i);
end`

Then display every `filtered_img` and choose the one that looks the less noisy.

Comment: what am asking is how to find or obtain the noise of an image ?  then finding the standard deviation is easy...

Comment: You simply cannot. You can't extract the noise from your image because you don't have the filtered image. What you want to do might be achieved by estimating/recognizing the noise with high level methods such as a neural network learning through denoised image data set, but you'll be there for a long haul...

Comment: then what am do for finding the standard deviation of noise of an image?

Comment: I'm not a machine learning expert, but I can tell that this would take you weeks to do it as a beginner...

Comment: is there any another method other than neural network for doing this??plz help me.....this is a small part of my main project during curricullam

Comment: that's the best easiest solution. Testing several combinations (of `mean` and `std`) and seek the one that approximate the best the noise of your image.

Comment: Well in that case i dont have another solution. Ps:  i see that you are new in stackoverflow so plz dont forget to choose a best answer among those provided :). Wish you good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can denoise the image, compute the difference between the raw image and the denoised version, and then compute the standard deviation of the difference.
For instance:

```
a=imread('input');
a=double(a);
b=imsharpen(a); %you may need to tune the parameters
diff=b-a;
noise=std2(diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the variance of noise in the image assuming that you know the distribution. You will know this if you have read some of the great works in image denoising field by Donoho & John.

To find the noise std. dev. of noise in an image with Gaussian contamination (additive), you can use the Median Absolute Deviation (MAD) estimator on the derivative of the image using the following kernel:

I am writing the python code for this, you can easily write it in Matlab:

```
def find_stddevs(img):
    k = np.asmatrix([[-1.0/9, -1.0/9 ,-1.0/9],
                     [-1.0/9, 8.0/9 , -1.0/9],
                     [-1.0/9, -1.0/9 ,-1.0/9]])

        filtered = convolve(img,k,mode='reflect')
        median_a = np.median(filtered)
        stddev = np.median(np.absolute(filtered - median_a))/0.67449 #Gaussian noise assumption
        return stddev
```

You can see the derivation and the logic [Here on Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation#relation_to_standard_deviation)

Again, most people think it can be done. This is true iff you do not have any prior about the type of contamination in the image.